# FFMPEG and Wi-Fi Internet connection drop

Tags: wireless-networking, ffmpeg, internet, nvidia-graphics-card, wifi-driver

I've encountered a strange issue: 
my Wi-Fi internet connection drop off while converting files with -vcodec h264_nvenc inside powershell.

As soon as the conversion is ended Wi-Fi start working again.

Since I receive a DNS PROBE error on every browser I've decided to change DNSs but I still have this issue

I'm using something like this:
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:20 -to 00:08:00 -i input.mov  -c copy -vcodec h264_nvenc -vf scale=2560:1440 -b:v 99000k output.mov

I suspect it is some conflict with my GPU but it seems very strange becaus it's only happening with this specific command in FFMPEG.

I'm actually using the Zeranoe build.

my build is
Intel i9-9900K
Z390 Aorus Pro
nvidia RTX 2080 Msi gaming trio

All drivers are up to date

thanks

Comment: Same here. Exactly the same problem. It's really weird. Let me know if you ever found out what was going on.